# How to limit content selector by docker tag in Sonatype Nexus3?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, sonatype, nexus3

How to only grant access to specific tags and specified namespaces in Sonatype Nexus3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, we will use an image with the name: `docker.domain.com/namespace/image:1.1.1`

We only want to allow the user to pull images that have a tag that matches our Semver regex. (you can simply adjust the regex to your own needs)

#### Content Selector

```
format == 'docker'  
&& (
    path == '/v2/' 
    || (
        path =~ '.*/namespace/.*' 
        && (
            path =~ '.*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
            || path =~ '.*/blobs/.*'
            )
        )
    )
```

#### Explanation

- `&&` AND operator
- `||` OR operator
- `==` EQUAL operator
- `=~` REGEX operator
- `format == 'docker'` sets the format type that should be selected
- `path == '/v2/'` grants login and manifest privileges as explained [docker v2 API specification](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)
- `path=~'.*/blobs/.*'` grants pull access to the image layers
- `path=~'.*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'` Semver-regex

The most important part is the combination of the namespace and Semver-regex, namespace and blobs path.

**Edit:**
Please see [rseddon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166420/rseddon)s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55503164/8247069) for a deeper explanation.

Comment: You just resolved in one post the question that's been turning in my poor mind for several weeks. Would you accept a hug ? :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Docker images are stored like this in Nexus:

[image]

The blobs are docker layers, and they can (and often are) shared between multiple docker images. This sharing of layers is the reason why docker is an efficient format for storing VM’s. But this also means that you can’t restrict access to layers, you can only restrict access to manifests and tags. So you’ll need to create a content selector privilege that allows access to all layers.

Additionally, you need to allow access to `/v2/` for docker login, and `/v1/search` for search.

So you’ll need a content selector privilege like this that allows access to the things everyone needs:

```
path =~ "/v2/|/v2/blobs/.*|/v2/search/.*"
```

After this, you can selectively allow access to manifests and tags by using content selectors like this:

```
path =^ "/v2/some-docker-image/"

path =^ "/v2/library/ubuntu/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only possible with a lot of effort. (Nexus 3.41 Pro)

Biggest challenge:

1. Open Nexus Browser and locate any image directory with tags and manifest folders. Click on any tag (i.e. latest), see path property (/v2/library/image/**manifests**/latest. Open it.
2. What docker will try is get the latest-manifest, look inside, find [?].digest (sha256:...), depending on it system arch, open this manifest --> /v2/library/image/**manifests**/sha256... check for layer blobs to download
3. That means /v2/library/image/**manifests**/sha256... has to be accessible. Sadly, if it is accessible, you just can pull any version of the image directly via (nexusurl:port/image@sha) and bypass any tag specific restrictions set by content selectors.

That means this is only possible (without a direct bypass) if one maintains a list of tags and manifest hashes of the allowed images.
This is only feasable with automated IaC Plugins (if required for a lot of images with continuous version changes).

A better solution might be to set up the repo not as proxy and instead as mirror, and have a job pulling all allowed images from dockerhub und pushing them into the mirror repo.